# What's the difference between the g and m modifiers in Javascript regexes?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript regular expressions, you can put in a 'g' modifier for global, and 'm' for multiple. What's the difference between them, or are they the same thing?

Comment: I misread multiline as multiple :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`m` does not stand for "multiple", but for "multiline". And it makes `^` and `$` match at line beginnings and line endings, respectively (instead of just the beginning and ending of the string).

Well, and `g` really means "global", so that the regex engine continues to find further matches after the first one.

[Further reading about regex modifiers.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

`/m` could be thought of the enhance mode modifier for `/g`.

Here is a sample test:

```
hello my darling 
you are so sweat
and hello my beauty
hello my lady
you are so kind
hello my heartbeat
you drum like a spring wind
```

`/^hello/g` : regard all content as a entirety which means it will match the entire string from the beginning "hello" to the end "wind".

> `/g` use for match the entire string from the beginning "hello" to the end

```
**hello** my darling
you are so sweat
and hello my beauty
hello my lady
you are so kind
hello my heartbeat
you drum like a spring wind
```

`/^hello/gm` : will match the 1,4,6 line singly.

> `/gm` use for match the entire string too, but it will split the entire string > by line break and it will test each line with the pattern given (line by line) > instead of just test the beginning to the end of the entire string simply.

```
**hello** my darling 
you are so sweat
and hello my beauty
**hello** my lady
you are so kind
**hello** my heartbeat
you drum like a spring wind
```

hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Helpful example indeed